# Why I can checkin a document (overwrite) even when I have removed the Delete Versions

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I have a Sharepoint library, and I have Contribute without delete permissions assigned to UserA. Contribute permissions without Delete Items and Delete versions permissions.

My question is: Why can UserA overwrite a file in the sharepoint library? If he does not have permissions to delete previous versions, then I would think that it would not be able to checkin/overwrite other versions.

Answer (score 0):

UserA can overwrite a file and create versions because the UserA has rights to do. When UserA overwrite a file it will create a new file with different version. Creating version is different from deleting a file.